# Proving a sequence will always be positive and less than 5 with induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

Im having trouble figuring out this question, I am able to prove the base case but do not know how to go about it after that:

Deﬁne the sequence an inductively by $a_1 = 1$ and
$a_{k+1} =\frac{6a_k + 5}{a_k + 2}.$

Prove that (i) $a_n > 0$ and (ii) $a_n < 5$ for all positive integers $n.$

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be that hard to prove that $a_k > 0$ for all k. What have you tried?

Comment: im struggling more with the second part and proving all an<5

Comment: I suggest updating your question (click "Edit" above) to include your proof of part (i), because other users are moving to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

After a little  simplification, we get,

a<sub>k+1</sub> = 6 - 7/(a<sub>k</sub> + 2)... (1)

And,
a<sub>k</sub> = 6 - 7/(a<sub>k-1</sub> + 2)

Hence,

a<sub>k+1</sub> - a<sub>k</sub>

= 7/(a<sub>k-1</sub> + 2) - 7/(a<sub>k</sub> + 2)

= 7*(a<sub>k</sub> - a<sub>k-1</sub>) / [(a<sub>k-1</sub> +  2)*(a<sub>k</sub>  + 2)]... (2)

Therefore,  if a<sub>k</sub> is bigger than a<sub>k-1</sub> then a<sub>k+1</sub> is bigger than a<sub>k</sub>.
But a<sub>2</sub> is bigger than a<sub>1</sub> . Which implies that the sequence  is an increasing one and that proves (i)

Furthermore, from (1) a<sub>k+1</sub> + 7/(a<sub>k</sub>  +  2) = 6

Or,

a<sub>k</sub> + 7/(a<sub>k</sub> + 2) < 6

(a<sub>k</sub>)² + 2*(a<sub>k</sub> ) + 7 < 6*(a<sub>k</sub> ) + 12

=> (a<sub>k</sub> - 5) * ( a<sub>k</sub> + 1) < 0

=> a<sub>k</sub> < 5 (since (a<sub>k</sub> + 1) is clearly positive) ,  and that proves (ii)

Answer (score 0):

By an easy induction, we get $a_n > 0$ for all positive integers $n$.

Next we show $a_n < 5$ for all positive integers $n$.

Proceed by induction on $n$.

For the base case, note that $a_1 < 5$.

Next assume $a_n < 5$ for some positive integer $n$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
a_{n+1} < 5
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
\frac{6a_n+5}{a_n+2} < 5
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
6a_n+5 < 5(a_n+2)\qquad\bigl(\text{since $a_n + 2 > 0$}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
6a_n+5 < 5a_n+10
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
a_n < 5
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is true by the inductive hypothesis.

Thus, $a_n < 5$ implies $a_{n+1} < 5$, so the induction is complete.